# Observable does not emmiting a new value

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have my observable difined like that:

```
 dropDownValue$: Observable<number> = Observable.of(-1);
```

Then I have another `observable` that I am subscribing to

```
 this.actions$.pipe(
      ofAction(UpdateFormValue)
    ).subscribe((action: any) => {
      this.dropDownValue$ = Observable.of(action.payload.value.data);
    });
```

And finally my obserable `dropDownValue$` that I am expecting getting the new value from the `subscibe` block above, but just nothing happend, no new value getting recieved.

```
this.dropDownValue$.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

What I am doing wrong? 
Is there anyway to achieve what I am trying to do without `BehaviorSubject` ? Or `BehaviorSubject` is the way to go?

Comment: That means action.payload.value.data is not a number

Comment: @siva636 it is definetly number, I just double check with `typeof action.payload.value.data` also I changed the `dropDownValue$: Observable<number> = Observable.of(-1);` to `dropDownValue$: Observable<any> = Observable.of(-1);` - didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you override the Observable of `dropDownValue$` on a new action. It means that any previous subscribers of `dropDownValue$` are subscribed to different Observable, and they would never get a value.

An alternative of using a Subject for `dropDownValue$` would be to build `dropDownValue$` as chained Observable that starts from `action$`:

```
this.dropDownValue$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofAction(UpdateFormValue),
  mergeMap((action: any) => Observable.of(action.payload.value.data))
);

this.dropDownValue$.subscribe(console.log);
```